# UITableView row is deleted but not hidden

Tags: ios, uitableview

I a slidable tableView cell and in the cell there is a button to delete the row. I have this code inside my method to delete the row. The content of the row is correctly deleted from the DataSource but I am having trouble on hiding and reloading my tableView. Here is my code:

```
- (void)deleteElementAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [dateTableView beginUpdates];

    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    listTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    listTitles = [[user objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy];

    [listTitles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [user setObject:listTitles forKey:@"listTitles"];
    [user synchronize];

    [dateTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [dateTableView endUpdates];
    [dateTableView reloadData];
}
```

My class has the delegate and dataSource protocols. Here are also my delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"reloading...numberofsection");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"reloading...numberofrowsinsection");

    return [listTitles count];
}
```

Comment: Show your data source methods, numberOfRows and numberOfSections

Comment: If you are calling begin/end updates. You shouldnt be calling reloadData.

Now since reload data isn't giving what you want I think your backing data is not correct.

Comment: Added more code. As I said, all my code is working and the element from my array it's been deleted. The table view is not reloading though.

Comment: Can you insert a breakpoint in number of rows to see if it gets called when you reload the data

Comment: I have a NSLog and it's not called....weird. But when I add an element to the data source a few seconds before this, it's called.

Comment: This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

```
- (void)deleteElementAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // [dateTableView beginUpdates]; This shouldn't be placed here

    NSLog(@"This method was called: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)); // Check if this method is even called       

    // NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; don't bother creating a new object

    // listTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; Since you are reinitialising down below this is not needed

    // listTitles = [[user objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy]; Don't bother creating a new object

    [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [dateTableView beginUpdates];
    [dateTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [dateTableView endUpdates];

    // Now try this - THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT CHANGE: calling -setNeedsDisplay**
    [dateTableView reloadData];
    [dateTableView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

A few other things:

> My class has the delegate and dataSource protocols. Here are also my delegate methods:

The `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `-numberOfRowsInSection:` are both data source methods, make sure you have implemented the other compulsory one `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, your delegate methods are like `-commitEditingStyle:`: and `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

[Also this is a good open source cell swiping project](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell)

Comment: This is wrong. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` won't do anything, and calling `reloadData` is wrong because you just enqueued an animation. `endUpdates` starts an animation that would get immediately interrupted by the next line. Generally you either modify your table view row-by-row or you refresh the whole thing by calling `reloadData`. You're trying to do both here, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Take out these lines -

```
listTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

listTitles = [[user objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy];

[dateTableView reloadData];
```

And then make absolute complete sure your IBOulets are connected. I see that you're using a tableView instance named `dateTableView` which indicates that you are using a custom UIViewController class. If you used Interface Builder for this you have to make sure that you've connected up the Outlet to the table. If not, calling dateTableView somewhere is like sending a message to nil.

Comment: Are you saying that the row does not delete? Question: are you SURE your IBOutlets are connected?

Comment: I can almost guarantee that's what it is. I had the same issue before, pull my hair out type stuff, but tableView was not connected to the IBOutlet, although the delegate and dataSource were.

Comment: DataSource, delegate and outlet already connected. Also in the viewDidLoad through code.

Comment: try NSLog(@"%@",dateTableView); and see what prints

Comment: My array is (null) and also dateTableView is (null). Always because I deleted the only element which was in it.

Comment: dateTableView should not be NULL. Double and triple check that you have connected the IBOutlet in Interface Builder. If you have values inside the tableView then it is connected to the dataSource and delegate. It's missing a connection somewhere

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35103/discussion-between-balestrapatrick-and-justin-amberson)

Answer (score 0):

The allocation for the NSMutableArray is useless as you're overriding the variable in the next line. The reloadData is also not needed if you call beginUpdates and endUpdates.

Make sure the indexPath you pass as argument has the correct Section in it, maybe the tableview tries to remove the row at a wrong section. If the section is correct, you should check your implementation of your UITableViewDataSource.

Verify that

```
listTitles = [[user objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy];
```

doesn't return NIL. Otherwise every new methods you call on this object will have no effect. You should also log the returned cell count from the numberOfRowsInSection:. By the way a cleaner implementation would be:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * listTitles;
@synthesize listTitles;

- (void)deleteElementAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [dateTableView beginUpdates];

    [self.listTitles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [user setObject:self.listTitles forKey:@"listTitles"];
    [user synchronize];

    [dateTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [dateTableView endUpdates];
}
```

In the constructor (or viewDidLoad for a controller), do the following

```
self.listTitles = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"listTitles"] mutableCopy];
if (self.listTitles == nil) {
    self.listTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: It looks like that my indexPath is correct. When I NSLog it and I delete the first row: "2 indexes [0, 0]"

Comment: The problem is that the tableView is reloading its dataSource before deleting the object. Look at my debugger: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/1568/np0w.png

Comment: Oh no, it's not reloading the tableView. Look at the time. I think that endUpdates is not called...